# log4j2 and slf4j/logback differ in output in anylogic

Tags: log4j2, logback, slf4j, anylogic

I inherited an anylogic project where parts of the model logic have been implemented in a java project, from which this model is also launched.

This project has multiple logger configurations since in most parts of the project log4j2 is used, in few parts it is slf4j which uses the logback backend.

In the anylogic UI/Browser-Window, you can view some *Console* in which some output is printed:

[image]

Interestingly there are no logs printed, that haven been recorded with the log4j-library.
Those beeing recorded with slf4j and logback however, are also shown in the *Console*.

The appender configurations read like this:

```
# log4j2 appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
```

```
<!--- logback.xml appender --->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%highlight(%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %msg%n)</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Now for the question: **What is difference between the two logging frameworks/appenders, that can cause the observed behavior?**

Comment: Please feel free to ask for more details, if that helps to solve that riddle. `System.out.println` output is also shown in the `Console`-panel.

Comment: Are you sure that the log4j2 console messages are the ones not being shown, and the SLF4J/Logback ones are (since I know of reasons why the opposite would happen)? Also, your screenshot seems to contradict your Logback config: the blue message there (presumably one of the SLF4J messages which shows) doesn't have the pattern specified in your Logback config file.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Indeed, there are few log statements using SLF4J/Logback. The blue messages in the screen shot are the more frequent ones, using System.out.println - as mentioned, the logging (among other things) don't... exactly live up to Clean Code Standards or anything like that. It feels more like a "copy&paste-programming"-project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the [`SYSTEM_OUT` *is reassigned after configuration*.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender)

If I set the Log4J2 Console Appender to follow

```
appender.console.follow = true
```

The log is also appended to the console in the AnyLogic UI.
Apparently logback *follows* by default.